# Query in JayData

Tags: jaydata

I want to query a simple sqLite database and get all the values and print them in a `<div>` .
The Database Table just has person "names" and corresponding "Contact numbers" as columns.
Please Explain the logic to do so.

Comment: Do you have an ID field in that table?

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to existing sqLite databases is not officially supported by the current version, JayData needs to build its database schemas in order to operate. You might try to create a JavaScript schema that just maps to the existing sqLite schema and see if JayData let's you work with it but it is really a tough scenario.

If you let JayData manage the table for you then

*Create SQL table:*

```
var Person = $data.define("Person", {
   name: String,
   contact: String
});
```

*Push some data:*

```
Person.addMany([{name: 'john'}, {name:'jane', contact: '555-1234'}]);
```

*Retrive data and put to div*

```
Person.readAll().then(function(persons) {
    persons.forEach(function(person) {
       $('#list').append(person.name);
    });
});
```

If you are interested in this approach you can read more on the [JayData ItemStore API.](http://jaydata.org/blog/the-itemstore-api-101)