# Access Sqlite database using JayData for Android/Phone Gap

Tags: android, cordova, jaydata

I have an android application that uses a SqLite database. Now i want to create the same application using Phone Gap. I need to use [Jaydata](http://jaydata.org/) to connect to the same Sqlite Database. I have gone through the documentation but could not find out where to place the database file so that it can be accessed from my application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to place the database to a specific folder, JayData will create it for you (this is the supported method). More info in the thread - [Query in JayData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409014/query-in-jaydata)
You can add a init mechanism that recognizes the first start of the app and inserts the necessary records to you DB - for example from a file.

Comment: Thanks Robesz , Does that mean that i have to create the database all over again with all the tables in jaydata?

Comment: No, not at all, only at the first time. The database stays there and will be available during the following app starts.

Comment: Ok i got it , but is there any way i can use my existing database? My database is pretty big one and i dont want to create it again.

Comment: I would have shared it, but unfortunately there isn't a supported way. The recommended way is to export your data to a file and instert the data from the file unsing JayData during the first start of the app.